# Setting default text of select box depending on another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, default

I have question regarding the ability to set the default text of a selectbox depending on what the default text is of another selectbox.

I am trying to populate a country and state drop down list, where the state options change in regards to what country you have chosen.  However, when no country is chosen, I would like the state selectbox to say "Please Choose a Country".  Right now it just says "State" otherwise.

In other words, if the country select box just says "Country" I want the state select box to say "Please choose a country".  And once the user chooses something in the country selectbox, the state selectbox **won't say** "Please choose a country" anymore.

---

### Simple example of what I have

Country <.select id="country" name ="country">

State <.select id="state" name ="state">

I am an inexperienced programmer so I am not sure what functions can possibly be used.  Would this be accomplished with jQuery?  I appreciate any help in regards to this matter and I hope my question wasn't confusing.  Thank you.

Comment: i assume you put the data dynamically?why not put the data for state when you have already chosen a country by default the state is empty. when you change the country that is when you populate the state depending on the country?

Comment: wow, very simple.  I am embarassed that I even asked the question.  Thank you.  I have accomplished what I wanted to accomplish

Comment: glad it works for you happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily accomplish that using the jquery.

Check out the plunker i created as below

https://plnkr.co/edit/V2VcU20olauex8IBtKC2?p=preview

```
<select id = "Country" onChange="func()">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  </select>
<select id = "State">
  <option value="new">
  Please select the country</option>
  </select>
```

in script file.

```
var func = function(){
var state = {
  'ABC' : 'abc',
  'DEF' : 'def'
}

var sel = $('#State');

$.each(state, function(key, value) { 
    $("#State option[value='new']").remove();
    sel.append('<option value="'+value+'">'+key+'</option>');
});};
```

Answer (score 0):

As @guradio suggested, you could fill the "states" options when a country is selected.

As for the default "Please Choose a Country" at the beginning, or when no country is selected :

```
<select id="country">
 <option selected>Country</option>
</select>

<select id="state" disabled>
 <option selected disabled>Please provide a Country</option>
</select>
```

```
var Country = {
  "Australia" : ["New South Wales","Victoria","Northern Territory","Queensland"],
  "B" : ["1","2","3","4","5","6"],
  "C" : ["1","2","3","4"],
  "D" : ["1","2","3","4", "5"]
}

//Add the countries
$.each(Country, function(key,value) { 
  $("#country").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+key+'</option>');
});

//On country change
$("#country").change(function(){
    //Get country choosen
  var countryChoice = $("#country option:selected").text();

  if (countryChoice !== "Country") {

    $("#state option").remove();

    //Add states from country
    $.each(Country[countryChoice], function(key,value) { 
        $("#state").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
    });
    //If new country is valid, enable state choice
    $('#state').prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else {
    //Else, replace selection with "Please provide a state"
    $("#state option").remove();
    $("#state").append('<option selected disabled>Please provide a Country</option>');
    $('#state').prop("disabled", true);
  }
})
```

Here's a JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0e01j4gr/1/)

Comment: Great.  Thank you very much!